# Can I disguise myself as a guard?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Can I disguise myself with the armor of a guard I just killed, or do they always know who I am? Could I pass as a hold guard and get away with anything I want?

Comment: Well, you *can*, but you probably won't be fooling anybody but yourself.

Comment: I imagine you would have to equip everything from a helmet to gauntlets to weapons (correct shield belonging to that clan), so it'd be a huge pain. It would be cool to have a quest where this is your goal.

Answer (score 5):

No, it doesn't work. Guards will still know it's you.

Comment: Fallout:New Vegas allows for this (you can wear faction armor disguises, for example), and Oblivion has the [Gray Cowl of Nocturnal](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Gray_Cowl_of_Nocturnal) although you are correct that there is no such mechanic in Skyrim.

Comment: Oh, that's cool! I haven't played NV yet. I thought about the Cowl, but it's not quite the same thing.

Comment: Hitman's all ABOUT disguises.  Just don't get too close.

Comment: Alright, well I couldn't think of any game *I've* played that does that :P

Comment: Skyrim Redone has disguises.

Comment: Thank u posters that would be cool. I do not hav fallout anymore so I would not know the while disguising thing

Comment: *cough* TF2 disguises *cough*

Comment: @badp Eh, not quite the same.

Answer (score 1):

Disguises do actually work, but only to an extent. I was watching Jesse Cox play skyrim, and in the Thalmor embassy he attempted to disguise himself as one of them. When he approached some Thalmor, they didn't immediately attack him, and they said that they didn't recognize him, and they wanted him to come so they could see his face. They would have probably attacked after a few seconds, if he didn't just then get attacked by 2 dragons.

Comment: If you want to see for yourself, go to his channel OMFGcata, and look at episode 48 of his skyrim playthrough.